# Join/merge 2 json depending on a conditional in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have 2 json files, in one I have policies and in the another one I have clusters with custom configurations, the thing is if a cluster has a policy_id key, it should be merged/join with the respective policy to get its default configurations, if not just returns the base cluster.

cluster.json

```json
[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "memory": 16
    },
    {
        "name":"b",
        "memory": 16,
        "policy_id": 2
    }
]
```

policies.json

```
[
    {
        "policy_id": 1,
        "policy_name": "test",
        "policy_cores" :  4
    },
    {
        "policy_id": 2,
        "policy_name": "test2",
        "policy_cores" :  8
    }
]
```

So the expected result should be something like this, the "a" cluster remains the same because doesn't have a `policy_id` key, the "b" cluster has its values and policy's values:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "memory": 16
    },
    {
        "name":"b",
        "memory": 16,
        "policy_id": 2,
        "policy_name": "test2",
        "policy_cores" :  8
    }
]
```

I was trying to do it in the locals block code but I don't know how I can do nested for loops with the conditional. Sorry for the pseudo code, I code in Python so Terraform is so rare for me.

```
locals {
    # get jsons
    policies = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/policies.json"))
    clusters = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/clusters.json"))

    #pseudo-code to express the logic, sorry im still learning Terraform
    aux_clusters = [
        for cluster in local.clusters : {
            if try(cluster.policy_id, null) != null : {
                #if policy_id key exists, then merge with the respective policy
                for k, v in local.policies : {
                    k => merge(v, cluster) if v.policy_id == cluster.policy_id
                }
            } else {
                #if policy_id key doesnt exist just return the base cluster
                cluster
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Greate question. I also had a similar problem and found a solution using `merge` and `try`.

```
locals {
  clusters = [
    {
      "name" : "a",
      "memory" : 16
    },
    {
      "name" : "b",
      "memory" : 16,
      "policy_id" : 2
    }
  ]
  policies = [
    {
      "policy_id" : 1,
      "policy_name" : "test",
      "policy_cores" : 4
    },
    {
      "policy_id" : 2,
      "policy_name" : "test2",
      "policy_cores" : 8
    }
  ]
  policies_map = {
    for policy in local.policies : policy.policy_id => policy
  }

  aux_clusters = [
    for cluster in local.clusters : merge(
      cluster,
      try(
        local.policies_map[cluster.policy_id],
        {}
      )
    )
  ]
}

output "aux_clusters" {
  value = local.aux_clusters
}
```

I have not tested for all cases and could imagine that it will have some issues if `policies` have entries with duplicates of `policy_id`.